# Smoked meat too smokey tasting

Tags: brining, smoking, science

I bought a large quantity of smoked cuts of pork (Ham, Sausage and bacon) and find it is too smokey.  Is there anything I can do prior to cooking or method of cooking that will lessen the smoked taste?

Answer (score 1):

You can soak it, or you can boil it in several changes of water, or both (then bake to finish if that's what you want, or dry it then fry or grill it in the case of bacon).

This works better for smaller pieces so you may want to cut it into the minimum acceptable size first.

Slow cooking a gammon joint in plenty of cider or apple juice, possibly spiced, can help to mask the smokiness. You can throw in roughly chopped apple and/or onion as well.